# How can I query an XML element with XSL and return the result?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML list of date ranges (Periods) with Start and End dates.  I need to query the list and return the Start element (or position) when I find a match but I am not sure how I can accomplish this.

Here's sample data:

```
<Calendar>
    <Period>
        <Start>20150501</Start>
        <End>20150514</End>
    </Period>
    <Period>
        <Start>20150515</Start>
        <End>20150531</End>
    </Period>
    <Period>
        <Start>20150601</Start>
        <End>201506014</End>
    </Period>
    <Period>
        <Start>20150615</Start>
        <End>201506030</End>
    </Period>
<Calendar>
```

I've used this XPATH to find my ouput, but how can I return the element value of Start or perhaps the Position?

```
//Calendar/Period[Start <= '20150518' and End >= '20150518']
```

Returns:

```
/Calendar[1]/Period[2]
```

I am looking for the output to be either the Start value or Position:  from my example '20150515' or 2.

The XML is the response from a web service call so I don't have access to a file.

Thanks!

Comment: consider editing your question to include our required output. Right now, I don't see anything wrong with /Calendar[1]/Period[2]. Good luck.

Comment: I've updated my question to include the desired output of '20150515' or 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's half an answer, relying on ubuntu's `xmllint`.

```
xmllint --xpath '/Calendar/Period[Start <= 20150518 and End >= 20150518]/Start/text()'
```

returns

```
20150515
```

But there will be no `\n` character at the end. Which means that your cmd-line would look like

```
20150515mPrompt >
```

*(Also note that using '//' at the front when you have actually specified a full path is often flagged on S.O. by the true XMLSLT gurus as computationally expensive and unneeded. I have switched to `/Calendar/...`. AND that  the quoting of the date values is not needed, so only `20150518`, not `'20150518'` is needed (at least in `xmllint`).*

I've spent way too much time researching the correct syntax to append a `\n` but haven't found it. I guess this behavior is considered a feature in XML-land. Apparently the only solution is a hack. IHMO, The easiest one to understand is

```
xmllint --xpath '/Calendar/Period[Start <= 20150518 and End >= 20150518]/Start' \
| sed 's@<[/]*Start>@@g;s/$/\n/'
```

produces

```
20150518
```

(I'm writing this on one machine and testing on another).

Finally, if, A. you're doing this in a *nix shell scripting environment and B. you want to use that value later one, the the simpliest thing would be to use cmd-substitution to capture the value into a shell variable, like

```
startDate=$(xmllint --xpath '/Calendar/Period[Start <= 20150518 and End >= 20150518]/Start/text()')

echo "my StartDate = ${startDate}'
my StartDate = 20150518
```

As far as returning the position, I couldn't find an xpath function that works in  xmllint. Based on the list of functions at [XML Cheetsheet](http://xpath.alephzarro.com/content/cheatsheet.html), I would have expected

```
xmllint --xpath '/Calendar/Period[Start <= 20150518 and End >= 20150518]/Start/position()'
```

to work, but only got

```
 XPath error : Invalid expresion
 xmlpathEval : evaluation failed
 XPath evaluation failure
```

Others are welcome to explain!

IHTH

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination! This works great.

Answer (score -1):

You can use XPATH for this `//Period[Start >= 20150501 and End <= 20150514]`

Give it a go [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html)

Comment: This is almost functionally identical to what the asker already has.